# Is it normal for my CPU to appear locked at 4.68 GHz when its base speed shows 3.6 GHz?

Tags: cpu

No games or anything significant is running on my PC. I noticed this and it just seems really weird, it seems to be locked a 4.68GHz:

[image]

I'm wondering if maybe I overclocked it and forgot. I'm pretty naïve as far as far as hardware goes. Does this really mean its running at 4.68GHz constantly, or am I misunderstanding the UI?

Comment: Your processor supports a boost clock to that frequency.  There is nothing wrong with your processor

Comment: There's 16% utilization though. I wonder if at least one core is nearly-fully loaded. Right click on the graph to see utilization per logical core.